# Error when linking C executable to OpenCV

Tags: opencv, linker

I'm compiling `OpenCV` under `Ubuntu 13.10` using `cMake`.

i've already compiled c++ programs and they works well.

now i'm trying to compile a C file using this `cMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (hello)
find_package (OpenCV REQUIRED)
add_executable (hello src/test.c)
target_link_libraries (hello ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

here is the `test.c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  IplImage* img = NULL; 
  const char* window_title = "Hello, OpenCV!";

  if (argc < 2)
  {
    fprintf (stderr, "usage: %s IMAGE\n", argv[0]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  img = cvLoadImage(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

  if (img == NULL)
  {
    fprintf (stderr, "couldn't open image file: %s\n", argv[1]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  cvNamedWindow (window_title, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  cvShowImage (window_title, img);
  cvWaitKey(0);
  cvDestroyAllWindows();
  cvReleaseImage(&img);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

it returns me this error whene running `cmake .` then `make` to the project:

```
Linking C executable hello
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/hello.dir/src/test.c.o: undefined reference to symbol «lrint@@GLIBC_2.1»
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [hello] Erreur 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/hello.dir/all] Erreur 2
make: *** [all] Erreur 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `-lm /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6`to your linked library

```
$ gcc `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o <output> <input> `pkg-config --libs opencv` -lm /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
```

I had the same errors and it worked with me

Answer (score -1):

Edit your `CMakeLists.txt` as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(test)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( test test.c )
target_link_libraries( test ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Then, $ `cmake .`
Then  $ `make` and finally $`./test`

Comment: You did nothing to the `CMakeLists.txt` but changing the project name, why did this should work ? (still not working for me)

Comment: Did you install cmake and gcc correctly? Your code works fine on my machine.

Comment: `gcc` is installed by default, and i've installed cmake with this command `sudo apt-get install cmake`. everything works fine when compiling c++ codes using the same library.

Comment: Your code runs perfectly fine on my machine. The reason I re-wrote CMakeLists.txt is that your's is small 'c' instead it should be CMakeLists.txt. Here's a run of ur code http://imgur.com/pEXgLym